# How to list all articles of the currently shown articles parent category

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-template

The list would serve as a sidebar menu next to the article. How should I do this?! From the article template, the only thing I managed to retrieve was the current articles category title, but I don't know how to get the category object itself:

```
$this->item->category_title
```

Is it possible to achieve this by changing or overriding the default article code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - no.  The template is for defining the layout of main content areas and module positions.

Extra functionality should be defined through [Joomla! extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org), for the particular functionality you're looking for you will need a module from the [Article Listing section](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing).

You haven't specified a version of Joomla! but we have previously used [ArtCats](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/5204) on Joomla! 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly it is possible. However, a module as *cppl* points out would probably be more nice. This requires a database query and is not really template/layout related. Anyway, this could probably do the trick:

In templates/your_template/html/com_content/article/default.php :

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('a.id, a.title');
$query->from('#__content AS a');
$query->where('a.catid = '.(int)$this->item->catid);
$query->where('a.state = 1');
$query->where('a.id != '.(int)$this->item->id);
$db->setQuery($query);
$articles = $db->loadObjectList();
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($articles as $item) : ?>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $item->title; ?></li>
    </ul>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```